# USB data transfer to iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, video, usb

First of all, this App will **not** go on the AppStore and is only for some Uni-Projects.

Is it possible to send data over USB to the iPhone and do some calculations with it on the iDevice? By that I mean just plugging the iPhone's USB charging cable into a self made device, and then allowing some data transfer, like video.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the standard USB cable can be plugged into a device -- that cable makes the iPhone act as a USB device, not as a USB host. You may be able to use the USB dongle from the iPad Camera Connection Kit for this, but don't expect much in the way of documentation.